# Mutate with dynamic column names dplyr

Tags: machine-learning, r, preprocessing, dplyr

Hi I have this dataset (It has many more columns)

```
   media   brand    radio        tv            cinema  
   <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>      
  radio      0      0             0                0     
  tv         0      0             0                0     
  cinema     0      0             0                0    
  tv         0      0             0                0   
  radio      0      0             0                0     
  tv         0      0             0                0
```

I want to obtain the following(Assign a 1 to each column based on the value of media column):

```
        media   brand    radio        tv            cinema  
       <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>            <dbl>      
      radio      0      1             0                0     
      tv         0      0             1                0     
      cinema     0      0             0                1    
      tv         0      0             1                0   
      radio      0      1             0                0     
      tv         0      0             1                0
```

Do you have any  idea on how to do it?As I have many more columns, I'm trying to find a solution using dynamic variable assignment.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called *one hot encoding* or *dummy encoding*. Even as this may be possible to accomplish in dplyr (together with tidyr), I would recommend using the function [*one_hot()*](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mltools/versions/0.3.5/topics/one_hot) from the library *mltools*. For an explanation, see the following code snippets:

```
# set up sample data
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:4,
  media = factor(c("radio", NA, "tv", "tv"), levels=c("radio", "tv", "cinema"))
)
```

**One Hot Encoding with tidyr:**

The following code snippet shows how you would accomplish one hot encoding with dplyr and tidyr (copied from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601217/how-to-convert-a-data-frame-to-one-hot-encoded#comment74252662_43601217) comment):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tib <- as_tibble(df)
tib %>% 
  mutate(i = 1) %>% 
  spread(media, i, fill = 0)
```

However, this code will give you the following table:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
 id    radio   tv   `<NA>`
<int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
  1      1      0      0
  2      0      0      1
  3      0      1      0
  4      0      1      0
```

Note that there is no *cinema* column present, even though we defined a respective level in our sample data-frame. Also, the *spread()*-function created an own column for values with NA's, treating them as a separate category.

**One Hot Encoding with mltools (recommended):**

```
library(data.table)
library(mltools)

dt <- data.table(df)
one_hot(dt)
```

This code will give you the following table:

```
id  color_radio  color_tv  color_cinema
1          1          0            0
2         NA         NA           NA
3          0          1            0
4          0          1            0
```

As you can see, the column *cinema* is now present even though our sample data-frame did not contain any observations of it. Also, there isn't an NA-column present anymore. The NA from the second row is instead visible in all columns (*which makes way more sense, since you don't know, what category this observation IS, so you cannot know what category it IS NOT*).

In addition, this code is not only easier to understand it also runs about two to three times as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Using mutating and ifelse you get the expected output:

```
# data:
df = tibble(
            media = c('radio','tv','cinema','tv','radio','tv'),
            brand = rep(0,6),
            radio = rep(0,6),
            tv = rep(0,6),
            cinema = rep(0,6)
            )
> df
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  media  brand radio    tv cinema
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 radio      0     0     0      0
2 tv         0     0     0      0
3 cinema     0     0     0      0
4 tv         0     0     0      0
5 radio      0     0     0      0
6 tv         0     0     0      0

df %>%
  mutate(radio = 1 * (media == 'radio'),
            tv = 1 * (media == 'tv'),
        cinema = 1 * (media == 'cinema')
        )

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  media  brand radio    tv cinema
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 radio      0     1     0      0
2 tv         0     0     1      0
3 cinema     0     0     0      1
4 tv         0     0     1      0
5 radio      0     1     0      0
6 tv         0     0     1      0
```